# How to Load content into div upon button press, long after page finishes loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have searched the web and forums high and low and have not found a solution that I feel accurately addresses it.  I hope someone reading this can help solve my issue.  I have a website that catalogs the concerts I have for various music groups.  Initially, all the dates, venues, and such for a given year are visible... a year 'row'.  Each date in the row is actually a link, as shown here:

```
<a name = "<?php echo $tag_no ?>" class="none" href="#<?php echo $tag_no ?>" title = "<?php echo $tooltip ?>" onClick="$('#<?php echo $tag_no ?>').load('/2.0/details.php3?event_no=<?php echo $tag_no ?>&amp;details=0&amp;PHPSESSID=<?php echo session_id() ?>');"><?php echo $concert_date_formatted ?> </a>
```

When the date is clicked, the .load() inserts the details for the concert into the div.  It actually replaces the year 'row' and inserts all the details in the div.  This has worked great for years.  I have a little javascript routine which attaches to the div and lets the user toggle it up and down...

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
// window shade
function change(id){ 
 ID = document.getElementById(id); 

 if(ID.style.display == "") 
      ID.style.display = "none"; 
 else 
      ID.style.display = ""; 
}
</script>
```

The issue I have is that I have added some content to the details that are inserted via the .load() that takes longer than I want to populate.  This happens before the page completes loading so it delays the overall list of dates and concerts from completing.

I need a way to make the content in the details load only after the user clicks the date.  I don't want the page to query the database and webserver until after the link is pressed.  I am using javascript and jquery in other areas.

Thanks for any insight!

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you do your database logic on a onclick event then? You don't know how to do that? Do you need a code sample?

Comment: Erick, if I understand you right, you are suggesting to add a onclick button to execute the database query in the details?  Perhaps I don't quite understand, but to me that would still run through with the initial load, can you give me an example?  that would be great/

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a button (in your case it seems is a date field):

```
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

You only want to load the content when the user clicks the button (or a date field). In this case, when the user clicks on it, the myFunction() will be executed.

In your myFunction(), you could have an AJAX event to bring the data from the DB.

```
function myFunction() {

//ajax event to bring data from database

}
```

Since you are Using JQuery, you can also do the following:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    //ajax event to bring data from database
});
```

Comment: Erick,  Confirm I understand this right.  I am using onlick with .load() which prefetches everything in the .load() upon page rendering.  If I just run it through a straight function, that will not execute until the button is pushed?

Comment: Exactly. That method will only execute when you click on the button.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl and come back in a day or so when I've tested it out a bit.  Thanks for the prompt response to my question!

Comment: Looks like this does the trick.  I'll do a full implementation sometime soon (the 14 hours without power 2 nights ago backed up everything)..I'll show this as solved.  Thanks Erick!